# Why I always Fail to "save_config" after finish setting wireless network use wpa_cli

Tags: wpa-supplicant

I have created file in /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf

ctrl_interface=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=wheel
update_config=1

Why always give me FAIL after save_config?

ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=wheel
update_config=1

also tried

Answer (score 0):

wpa_supplicant -B -i wlp3s0 -c /etc/example.conf
Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
CTRL: Invalid group 'wheel'
Failed to initialize control interface 'DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=wheel'.
You may have another wpa_supplicant process already running or the file was
left by an unclean termination of wpa_supplicant in which case you will need
to manually remove this file before starting wpa_supplicant again.

nl80211: deinit ifname=wlp3s0 disabled_11b_rates=0

Answer (score -1):

[Which configuration file is wpa_supplicant system are using ?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/umMI8.png)